# How to add multiple authors and multiple affiliations in Rmarkdown

Tags: r-markdown

In working with a Rmarkdown file, I would like to compile it so as to generate a Word file as output. Other similar questions here are more specific for Beamer(Latex). Any suggestion?

My session info is
R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

Answer (score 0):

The [`pandoc`](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#variables-set-by-pandoc) manual describes an `institute` field

> institute: author affiliations (in LaTeX and Beamer only). Can be a list, when there are multiple authors.

I don't think you'll be able to get multiple authors with affiliations to a Word file.

Comment: Thank you Ben. I suppose there must be a solution... I will look for it into the papaja project (producing apa journals manuscripts with Rstudio) https://github.com/crsh/papaja